# Why is NHibernate not removing entities from the 2nd level cache when they are updated?

Tags: nhibernate

I am using SysCache2 and NHibernate 2.1.2.4.

No matter how hard I try, NHibernate keeps loading previous instances of an entity.

My class is mapped as cacheable ReadWrite.

The cache region is the default, i.e. the full name of the class's types.

I am performing all actions within a transaction.

The database is definitely being updated, and when I manually clear ASP .NET's cache, the problem goes away.

I am doing a simple update, like this:

```
using(var transaction = NHSession.BeginTransaction())
{
    var foo = Session.Load<Foo>(_fooId);

    foo.Name = "A new name";

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Then I reload the entity later on (in a different session within the application), like this:

```
using(var transaction = NHSession.BeginTransaction())
{
    var foo = Session.Load<Foo>(_fooId);

    Response.Write(foo.Name);

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

... but Foo's name is still the old name, not the new name I just updated it to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked this one out - for certain reasons I had two Session Factories. I didn't realise that the Save operation was occurring within one factory, and the load was occurring in the other.

Answer (score 1):

I would log all the caching related messages and see if the cache is updated when the 2nd transaction is committed. Here is a sample log4net config to log caching messages...

```
<logger name="NHibernate.Cache.ReadWriteCache" additivity="false">
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Hi thanks I've checked the logs and the entity is not being invalidated when it is updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using Load instead of Get? I suspect this has something to do with the problem. [This article](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id) explains the differences but doesn't relate anything specific to your problem. Still, I would try switching to Get.

Comment: I don't understand how that could be the issue - Load is for loading a proxy only, whereas Get retrieves the whole entity immediately. Other than that I don't see how they are related to caching.

Comment: Get does check the 1st and 2nd level cache. The big difference is that Load will never return null; Get will return null if the entity does not exist. It doesn't make any sense to Load a property and then immediately access properties other than its ID, as you are doing. My guess is that the cached entity is not updated because you're updating a proxy, not the actual entity.

Comment: I don't think that make sense - as soon as you set a property of a proxy it should unproxy itself.